# How to make each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop in React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, function, loops, unique-key

Gather data →

```
    const gatherComps = (data) => {
        let competencyList = []
        let i = 1
        while (i < 6) {
          if (data && data.hasOwnProperty(`competency${i}`)) {
            competencyList.push(data[`competency${i}`])
          }
          i++
        }
        return competencyList
      }
```

Prep Data →

```
    const displayInfo = (singleCC, i) => {
        const result = singleCC.length
          ? singleCC.map((cc, ind) => {
              return ind < 1 ? (
                <div className="competencyHeadline">
                  <b>{cc}</b>
                </div>
              ) : (
                <div className="competencyDesc" key={ind}>
                  <i>{cc}</i>
                </div>
              )
            })
          : ""
        return (
          <div key={i}>
            <>{result}</>
          </div>
        )
      }
```

Return Data →

```
    <div className="Competencies">
        <div className="wrapper">
            {gatherComps(data).map((cc, i) => displayInfo(cc, i))}
        </div>
    </div>
```

I've tried:
`key={i}`
`` key={`custom-name-title-` + i.toString()} ``
`key={ind}`
`` key={`custom-name-desc-` + ind.toString()} ``
and some other simular things and can't get this warning to go away.

I've even included the same values for an id={} to make sure it continued to render a unique id, which it does, but I still get the warning...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing key value for `<div className="competencyHeadline">`. You have that one at first iteration of `.map`.

Just add custom key the same way you did:

```js
const displayInfo = (singleCC, i) => {
  const result = singleCC.length
    ? singleCC.map((cc, ind) => {
        return ind < 1 ? (
          <div className="competencyHeadline" key={ind}> <------------ HERE
            <b>{cc}</b>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div className="competencyDesc" key={ind}>
            <i>{cc}</i>
          </div>
        );
      })
    : '';
  return (
    <div key={i}>
      <>{result}</>
    </div>
  );
};
```